# Right way to set SSL validation in Java

Tags: java, security, ssl, amazon-s3, https

I am having a Jersey application, which basically retrieves an image file from S3 and do manipulations(resize etc) to get thumbnail. Finally, it stores thumbnail back into the very same bucket.

It works fine when SSL is disabled as shown.

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class TarkshalaPhotoLibraryApplication extends Application {

@SneakyThrows
public TarkshalaPhotoLibraryApplication() {
    // FIXME: 01/07/20 This is for sake of development, in production environment
    // legitimate certificate issuers are needed to be supplied
    disableSSLVerification();
}

private void disableSSLVerification() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
    };
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
}
}
```

I am doing it in jersey's application class.

What I understand by above code snippet is that, we are basically adding TrustManager that skips checking ssl certificates. Our trust manager should ideally be checking the certificate for which we will have to point right SSL-provider as well.

What I don't know is, where can I get correct SSL-Provider used by S3 and right way to check SSL  in Java.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not aware about S3, But To use SSL validation in java. 
You can get the certificate create a trust-store and keep that trust-store in class path. 
User JAVA_OPTS to point to the certificate JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path of truststore. 
Even you can use 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","trust store path");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");

Answer (score 1):

The drill goes like this:

1. Open the url you want to have the certificates for in the browser. Example URL: https://images.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/photo.jpg
2. The file does not need to exist. The important thing now is that TLS connection is validated correctly.
3. Click on the certificate details. Example in Chrome: [image: certification path]
4. The root certificate is the thing you need to put into your trust store.
5. Download it and put into your trust store. Profit.

Comment: Actually! we need not to set explicit certificate managers. Java takes care of it automatically if the certificate provider/validator is public. In my case, it was the issue because of recent changes in S3 object urls. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62736506/s3-object-url-is-not-securessl-when-opened-in-browser

Comment: your solution might be right for problems when certificate provider is unknown, but I have not tested it for that. Thank you for your time :)