# S3 object url is not secure(ssl) when opened in browser

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, https

I am building a small REST API service to store and retrieve photos. For that, I am using S3 as following:

```
public String upload(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                     Map<String, String> metadata, String group, String filename) {
    TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
            .withS3Client(amazonS3)
            .build();
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.setContentType(metadata.get(Configuration.CONTENT_TYPE_METADATA_KEY));
    // TODO: 26/06/20 Add content-type to metadata
    String filepath = group + "/" + filename;
    s3transferManager.upload(new PutObjectRequest(
            configuration.getProperty("aws.s3.bucket"),
            filepath,
            uploadedInputStream,
            objectMetadata)).waitForUploadResult();
    return amazonS3.getUrl(configuration.getProperty("aws.s3.bucket"), filepath).toString();
}
```

`url` returned by the function looks like https://photos.tarkshala.com.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default-group/1593911534320%230. When accessed it shows up like this
[image]

When I open it using the object url(https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/photos.tarkshala.com/default-group/1593911534320%230) given in AWS S3 console it shows up fine.

[image]

Why `getUrl` method not returning the second url or is there a way to get second method/api that does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of recent changes by AWS regarding s3.

> When using **virtual hosted–style buckets with SSL, the SSL wild-card
> certificate only matches buckets that do not contain dots (".")**. To
> work around this, use HTTP or write your own certificate verification
> logic. For more information, see Amazon S3 Path Deprecation Plan.

[amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)

Create a bucket without a dot or use the path style URL or you check [VirtualHostingCustomURLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs).

S3 support two types of URL to access Object.

- Virtual hosted style access

```
https://bucket-name.s3.Region.amazonaws.com/key name
```

- Path-Style Requests

```
https://s3.Region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/key name
```

**Important**

> Buckets created after September 30, 2020, will support only **virtual
> hosted-style requests**. Path-style requests will continue to be
> supported for buckets created on or before this date. For more
> information, see Amazon S3 Path Deprecation Plan – The Rest of the
> Story.

[S3 VirtualHosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html)

Comment: Got the point you explained. Will check and revert soon.

Comment: Yes, I changed the bucket name by omitting dots(.) out of it. Now it is working as expected.